# How to put the focus on Textbox

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a chat program. (javascript/html/css)
How can I put the focus on the field where i want to write my message?

Normally it's css code, isn't it?

The css of my message field looks like this right now:

Code:

```
#messageField {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #5a2300;
}
```

What do I have to add to the cursor there when my app starts?

Greetings

Comment: it's not CSS, it's JavaScript

Comment: What kind of element is the messageField?

Answer (score 3):

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function setFocus() {
      document.getElementById("messageField").focus();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id is bind to an `input` or `textarea` element, you can simply add this:

```
#messageField:focus {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #5a2300;
}
```